# How to Increase Bluetooth pairing window timeout in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, android-settings

I am trying to increase the timeout of the bluetooth pairing window (currently the window stays for only few seconds). Is there any way to achieve this action ?

[image: pairing window screenshot]

I have already tried methods from these stackoverflow links :

[How to pair Bluetooth device programmatically Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168263/how-to-pair-bluetooth-device-programmatically-android)

[How to programmatically pair a bluetooth device on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989902/how-to-programmatically-pair-a-bluetooth-device-on-android?rq=1)

[Android bluetooth, override pairing prompts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961726/android-bluetooth-override-pairing-prompts)

None of the above links have the answer what i am looking for, is there anybody to help me to solve this problem ? is there any method to increase the time-out of the bluetooth pairing screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ty this, the Pairing window will never timeout

```
public void pairDevice(final BluetoothDevice device) {

             String ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST = "android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_REQUEST";
             Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST);
             String EXTRA_DEVICE = "android.bluetooth.device.extra.DEVICE";
             intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE, device);
             String EXTRA_PAIRING_VARIANT = "android.bluetooth.device.extra.PAIRING_VARIANT";
             int PAIRING_VARIANT_PIN = 0;
             intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PAIRING_VARIANT, PAIRING_VARIANT_PIN);
             intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
             startActivity(intent);
}
```